# Unable to select item from dropdown list in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver ver 2.41 and Chrome ver 68.
I'm trying to get one item from dropdown list:

```html
<div id="loc_placeholder" class="jLocPlaceholder" style="">All locations</div>
    <select id="location_facet" name="location_facet" class="search_input font_bold multiselect jLocInput chzn-done" data-placeholder="All locations" multiple="" style="display: none;">
      <option value="233">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="250">Netherlands</option>
      <option value="228">United States</option>
```

etc.

And my question is: why this piece of code doesn't work ? I tried many times with other options but driver still cannot select any option :/

```
 WebElement location = driver.findElement(By.id("loc_placeholder"));
 location.click();

 Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("location_facet")));
 dropdown.selectByValue("250");
 //dropdown.selectByIndex(1);     
 //dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Netherlands");
```

I'm getting click on the dropdown and list is roll out.

Dependencies are:

```html
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I'm getting error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

(Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.75)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception while attempting to select the value?Is it possible for you to update the selenium library and chrome driver exe to latest versions and retry?

Comment: The dropdown has `style="display: none;`. Does it changes after clicking on the first element?

Comment: I got an error: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.75)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'

Comment: As the dropdown is hidden initially, try waiting for it to be visible/clickable

Comment: Do you mean to use Thread.sleep(1000); for example ? Actually I tried and unfortunately it didn't helped :(

Comment: Well - there has to be something else in there that will actually make the <select> become visible as part of the page - otherwise Selenium won't "see" it.  Any Javascript elsewhere on the page that would make it visible?  You could trigger that, then use the code that you have to select from the dropdown, once that element is visible...

Comment: @Guy, no it does not change after clicking on in. Stays the same: "style="display: none;"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help! :) I modified `style="display: none;` to `block` and after that it's visible.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("jQuery('#location_facet').css('display','block')");
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("location_facet")));
        select.selectByVisibleText("Netherlands");
```